# AVFoundation: copyCGImageAtTime always return nil

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to get all the frames from a video but it always fails at

```
cgImage = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
```

My current code in looks like this

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath {
        let fullPath = path + "/mov/watch_phone.mov"
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fullPath)
        mutableVideoURL = url
        getFrame()
        print(videoFrames.count)
    }

func getFrame() {
    let asset:AVAsset = AVAsset(URL:self.mutableVideoURL as NSURL)
    let assetImgGenerate:AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset:asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let duration:Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)
    let durationInt:Int = Int(duration)

    for index:Int in 0 ..< durationInt
    {
        generateFrames(assetImgGenerate, fromTime: Float64(index))
    }
}

func generateFrames(assetImgGenerate:AVAssetImageGenerator, fromTime:Float64)
{
    let time:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, 600)
    let cgImage:CGImage?

    do
    {
        cgImage = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil)
        let frameImg:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage:cgImage!)
        videoFrames.append(frameImg)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {

        print("Found error in saving entity changes \(error)")
    }
```

`copyCGImageAtTime` always returns nil.
The video is added to my bundle and also present in the bundle resources in Build Phases.

This is the error received in the catch block

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1700563e0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12430 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12430), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but for only iPhone 7+(ios 10.3.2). For iPhone x, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code. Try this and be sure you have non nil asset, correct time.

```
- (UIImage *)getUIImageOfVideoAsset:(AVAsset *)asset atTime:(CMTime)time withSize:(CGSize)size {

NSError *error;
AVAssetImageGenerator *baseImageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
baseImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
baseImageGenerator.maximumSize = size;

CGImageRef cgImage = [baseImageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&error];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);

return image;
}
```